# DataGridView Control doesn't draw cell backcolor correct

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i want to set backcolor of several cells in my DataGridView control. The Backcolor is setting dynamicaly while filling control with rows in  RowsAdded event handler. Here's the code

```
private void dataGridView_RowsAdded( object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e )
{
  if( dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value as string == "Color" ) 
  {
    dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].ReadOnly = true;
    SetCellColor( dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3], dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString()    );  
  }
}

private void SetCellColor( DataGridViewCell cell, Color clr )
{
  cell.Style.BackColor = clr;
  cell.Style.SelectionBackColor = clr;
}

private void SetCellColor( DataGridViewCell cell, string HEXColorVal )
{
  Int32 clrVal;
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo( "en-US" );
  if( Int32.TryParse( HEXColorVal, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, provider, out clrVal ) )
  {
    Color clr = Color.FromArgb( clrVal );
    SetCellColor( cell, clr );
  }
}
```

Here in the last column stored a srting representation of a color with transparency = 0. At runtime i can see, that  backgrounf properties are set to correct values, but in fact the background is stil white, and when i make this cell active everything becomes white also. What is the reason of this behaviour? i tried yo fix it with setting this properties in cellFormating event handler, but the result waas similar. At the same time, when i'm setting this properties using color from ColorDialog( which here appears on double click ), everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a problem in converting color from hex to color type. Just make it simple if the values are stored in grid like `#FFAABB`

```
private void SetCellColor( DataGridViewCell cell, string HEXColorVal)
{
  SetCellColor( cell, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(HEXColorVal));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of `Color.FromArgb` calls for supplying ARGB values. A is the Alpha channel; that's not the 'Transparency' but rather the 'Opacity'. I ranges form 0-255 or 00 to FF, with 00 being transparent and FF being solidly opaque.

If your input string omits the first of the 4(!) bytes the result will still be transparent.

You should make sure the Hex string has all four bytes and starts with a'FF'!

Or you could write this, explicitly separating the components:

```
 Color.FromArgb(255, (clrVal >> 16) & 0xFF, (clrVal >> 8) & 0xFF, clrVal & 0xFF);
```

Or you could write

```
 Color.FromArgb(255,  Color.FromArgb(clrVal) );
```

..silently correcting the alpha channel to full opacity.

Comment: It won't necessarily be transparent; it depends on the format of the hex value being passed in. If the hex string is in #RRGGBB format, then the alpha channel will be set to the value of RR. If it's in #BBGGRR format, then the alpha channel will be set to the value of BB. You might randomly get 0 or 255, but you could just as easily get something in between.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. AFAIK there is no such thing as a _format of the Hex string_: `Color.FromArgb()` takes an __integer__ with a fixed [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: He is parsing a hex string using `Int32.TryParse`, and then passing the result of that to `Color.FromArgb`. That's where the integer comes from.